# Sencha 2 cannot load html file into panel on Android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

there is a Sencha 2 bug with the ajax loader.

```
onActivate : function(result, container) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : this.getUrl(),
                        method : 'GET',
                        success : function(response, request) {
                            result.setHtml(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure : function(response, request) {
                            console.log("Failed: " + response);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

On Android 2.2, 2.3, IOS I have no problems. Android 4.0 have some problems to load this into the panel.

Any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging at all? Like, putting an `alert` into the success and failure methods? Does it get in there? Can you call `result.setHtml` outside of the Ext.Ajax.request method and it still works?

Comment: I can access the success part, but on Android 4.0 the "response.responseText" is empty, on Android 2.2, 2.3, 3.0,3.1,3.2 and IOS it is not empty. I can call result.setHtml outside the method but I do not have the requested html content. The only thing I can do is to write the whole html content as a string. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved it by myself.

There was an asynchronous issue in Ext.Ajax.request:

```
onActivate : function(result, container) {
            $.get("resources/web/about.html", function(data) {
                result.setHtml(data);
            });
        }
```

Hope it helps somebody who is annoying by the same issue.

Comment: So you fixed it by... not using Sencha Touch? :P